# How to filter links and pictures in tweets?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm developing wp8 app, using TweetSharp. All the links in tweets are look like t.co/aBRaKadABra. Part of links - pictures, rest - redirect to external pages. So, how can I detect that link is image? I want to put it in `<Image>`, and if it just link - put in `<HyperLink>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a HEAD request?

```
public static async Task<bool> IsUriImageAsync(Uri uri)
{
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest wc = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri); 
            //masquerade as a browser
            ((HttpWebRequest)wc).UserAgent = 
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.153.1 Safari/525.19";
            wc.Timeout = 1000;
            wc.Method = "HEAD";
            using(WebResponse res = await wc.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                return 
                  res.ContentType
                   .StartsWith("image/",StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }   
}
```